# Mediastream Recording API. ondataavailable is not triggered

Tags: webrtc, mediarecorder-api

I am trying to record media using the mediaRecorder API. Here is my code (just the relevant part). I expect to get a console log in saveChunks but it appears that the ondataavailable event is never triggered.I am able to see the video in the video element.

```
     recordedChunks = [];

     navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true})
      .then(function(stream) {
          myVideoMedia = document.getElementById("vid1");
          myVideoMedia.srcObject = stream;
          myVideoMedia.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
             myVideoMedia.play();
             mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
             mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = saveChunks;
             mediaRecorder.start();
             console.log(mediaRecorder);
        };
     })

     function saveChunks(event) {
       console.log("Data recorded...");
       //...
       };
     }
```

The console log of mediaRecorder.state is 'recording'
**I did try by passing a timeslice of 1000 to start() and its working now!** If no timeslice is passed, the function is called once at the end.